# KafkaConsumer polling issue

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to implement a Kafka consumer using Kotlin co-routines. I have placed the consumer `poll()` function inside the co-routine. For reading from multiple partitions, I have run two consumers subscribed to same topic with same group-id. The actual problem is that, the consumer `poll()` is turning into a long running function and hence utilizing all the worker threads.

The issue is only when I run two consumers with same group-id. When I run consumers with different group-id, there won't be such issue.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the exact problem?

Comment: When trying to run multiple consumers with same group id, the poll is not returning anything. Instead, it is getting blocked/becoming a long running operation (some kind of loop i believe). Hence, the worker threads are getting fully utilized and blocking the entire co-routines.

Comment: How many partitions do you have ? If you have only one partition, then only one consumer will be active at any given time.

Comment: Do the logs reveal anything? It seems you run into an issue with group rebalancing. However, unclear why this would happen.

Comment: I am having 2 partitions per topic and 2 consumers per topic. So, the partitions would be split across two consumers. @KamalChandraprakash

Comment: The logs does not reveal anything. It seems like a re-balancing issue. The issue is solved only if we set SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG to  less than 150ms and HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG to between 70 - 80 ms. In this case, there will be frequent re-balancing occurs and it gets solved in some way. This issue is there only when i try to implement kafka-consumer using kotlin co-routines. The traditional java threading style works fine. @MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: Not familiar with Kotlin. But if it's related to it, I cannot provide any better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use coroutines with poll. Coroutines should not used with blocking methods that take relatively long, and poll is such a method. I'm not sure there is a non-blocking poll available in the Java client, if it is, you should use that instead.